# HTML input text box placeholder not working outside of Visual Studio environment

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer

I have a html input textbox that has text in it which disappears when the user clicks into the box. This all works perfectly when developing inside visual studio (2010) with IE 10 and 11. However when I deploy to the live site the text in the placeholder is no longer visible? I think it's because VS runs in a different mode or something like that but how can I get it to work when the site is simply run by IIS?

```
<input name="query" type="text" id="search_input" placeholder="Search on Client Name or   Code"/>
```

Comment: There is something different about IE and running within VS for HTML5 containers.  Searches reveal conflicting answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try this to see if it works in both places:

```
<input id="example-email" type="text" value="Email Address" onfocus="if(this.value === 'Email Address') this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value === '') this.value = 'Email Address';" name="example-email">
```

Comment: hi there - yes that alternate way of doing it works just as well. Many thanks for that. Very much appreciated!

Comment: It's essentially what "placeholder" does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple jQuery alternative that I am using. This will find any element that has the `placeholder` attribute and toggles the placeholder in and out.

**HTML**

```
<input name="query" type="text" id="search_input" placeholder="Search on Client Name or Code"/>
```

**JS**

```
$('[placeholder]').on('focus', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).css('color', '#000000');
    }
});
$('[placeholder]').on('blur', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).css('color', '#A9A9A9');
        $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
    }
}).trigger('blur');
```